# How to get data of second and third table based of first table match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

This might be a continued question based on this one

[Get info from two tables in database where id match an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304445/get-info-from-two-tables-in-database-where-id-match-an-array/19304501?noredirect=1#19304501)

In the answer in above question i asked how to match data of two tables based on json file.

And nice guy explained it well in his example how i can store json data in array and query database only one time which is much faster than my try with foreach.

And this works great.

Well since json file is pulled from other website sometime it takes a bit more time to load a page because of json file so i decided to record json array into my own database and pull it from there which will make website load much much faster.

But im still on learning curve through mysql and don't know how to solve more complex things

So here is my tryout

```
    $gamesquery = mysqli_query($conn, 
            "SELECT steamgames 
            FROM members 
            WHERE steamID='$steam64id'");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($gamesquery);
    $gameslist = $data['steamgames'];

    $querygamename = mysqli_query($conn, 
            "SELECT sc_steamgames.*, sc_steamgameprices.* 
            FROM sc_steamgames 
            LEFT JOIN sc_steamgameprices on (sc_steamgames.appid=sc_steamgameprices.appid) 
            WHERE sc_steamgames.appid IN ($gameslist) 
            ORDER BY title");
```

which is working but is it possible to make it with one query only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF `steamgames` is comma delimited, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT sc_steamgames.*, sc_steamgameprices.* 
            FROM sc_steamgames 
            LEFT JOIN sc_steamgameprices on (sc_steamgames.appid=sc_steamgameprices.appid) 
            WHERE FIND_IN_SET(sc_steamgames.appid,(
                SELECT steamgames 
                FROM members 
                WHERE steamID='$steam64id'))
            ORDER BY title
```

Comment: Yes sir, this did it, content in steamgames is bunch of numbers comma delimited. Thank you very much this loads much faster than getting data from json file always.